# Insert struct element to ordered set fails

Tags: c++, insert, set

I need to insert struct of elements to a set as follows:

```
// In hpp file at private part of a class:
struct BestPair {
        unsigned int p1;
        unsigned int p2;
        double goodness;

        bool operator<(BestPair other) const                      // Set descendent order.                                    
        {
            return goodness > other.goodness;
        }
    };
```

The set should be in descendant order.

```
// at the cpp file, inside a method of the same class
void Pairs::fillGlobalStack (double *** source, unsigned int sz)
{
    BestPair bp;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = i+1; j != sz; ++j) {
            bp.p1 = i;        
            bp.p2 = j;
            bp.goodness = (* source) [i][j];
            global_stack.insert (bp);                          // Insert into global stack.                                   
            if (debug) {
                cout << "[fillGlobalStack] i: " << i << "  j: " << j << "  goodness: " << bp.goodness << "  global_stack.size\
() " << global_stack.size() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when run, the code never inserts the third, fourth and so on elements, which seem strange for me since they are different elements.

```
// The output:
[fillGlobalStack] p1: 0  p2: 1  goodness: 0  global_stack.size() 1
[fillGlobalStack] p1: 0  p2: 2  goodness: 0.794  global_stack.size() 2
[fillGlobalStack] p1: 0  p2: 3  goodness: 0.794  global_stack.size() 2  <-- It should be 3
```

What am I doing wrong? How to solve it?

Comment: @WhozCraig - it needs to in the sense that it could be more efficient, but that doesn't affect the meaning of the code.

Comment: What you did there, that's evil :) `operator<` that does greater-than comparison, heh.

Comment: @PeteBecker I never claimed it did, thus the "side note:" rather then "here's your problem.." But perhaps I will refrain in the future and only address the questions directly; a fair point.

Comment: @WhozCraig - your comment was legitimate, but needed a bit of qualification. I usually start comments like that with "this doesn't address your problem, but...".

Comment: @PeteBecker and "side note:" wasn't a sufficient way to do that? No matter, avoiding the situation in the future takes care of it by-default, so no worries.

Comment: @WhozCraig - sorry, I missed the "side note:".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two elements has equal `goodness` they are considered equal, and can't be stored in `set`. use `multiset` instead, if you want allow duplicates.

In general, elements considered equal if neither `a < b` and `b < a`

If you don't want to allow exact duplicates, but allow `goodness` - duplicates you should add any sorting you want if `goodness` are equal, e.g

```
bool operator<(const BestPair& other) const
{
    return goodness > other.goodness || goodness == other.goodnes && p1 < other.p1 || goodness == other.goodness && p1 == other.p1 && p2 < other.p2;
}
```

Comment: I thought that elements with equal goodness but different p1 and p2 would never be considered equal for the set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be three because your third element is equal to your second element (both have goodness 0.794). sets don't insert duplicates. Maybe you need `std::multiset` but it's hard to be sure. I wouldn't consider any kind of set to be a good implementation of a stack.